# Base64 encoding line by line faster way

Tags: bash, shell, base64

I have a kinda big text file (around 10GB) it fits without any trouble in to memory. My target is to convert every line to a base64 string. Currently my method takes forever and seems not to complete because it is single threaded.

```
while read line; do echo -n -i $line | base64 >> outputfile.txt; done < inputfile.txt
```

Can someone give me a hint how to do it faster? This solution creates around 100MB per hour (so finnishing time would be 100h) CPU usage is at 5% and also disk usage is very low.

Seems i got missunderstood about the control characters...
So i included a sample text file, and how the output should be (chepner was correct with the chomp):

Sample Input:

```
Банд`Эрос
testè!?£$
``
▒``▒`
```

Sample Output:

```
user@monster ~ # head -n 5 bash-script-output.txt
0JHQsNC90LRg0K3RgNC+0YE=
dGVzdMOoIT/CoyQ=
YGA=
4paSYGDilpJg

user@monster ~ # head -n 5 perl-without-chomp.txt
0JHQsNC90LRg0K3RgNC+0YEK
dGVzdMOoIT/CoyQK
YGAK
4paSYGDilpJgCg==

user@monster ~ # head -n 5 perl-chomp.txt
0JHQsNC90LRg0K3RgNC+0YE=
dGVzdMOoIT/CoyQ=
YGA=
4paSYGDilpJg
```

So samples are everytime better then human declarations ;=)

Comment: What version of `echo` supports a `-i` option?

Comment: By default, `base64` inserts newlines into long encoded lines; you probably want to avoid that by using the option `-w0`. And if your input file contains NULs (which would mean that it is not really a text file), then they will not be preserved by reading into a shell variable.

Comment: It is very unpleasant that you gave me a minus, arguing that this is what I answered for Windows, at a time when the question "in your understanding" was about Linux.
Have you seen the word Linux anywhere in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help a little to open the output file only once:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo -n $line | base64; done < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

`bash` is not a good choice here, however, for two reasons: iterating over a file is slow to begin with, and you are starting a new process for each line. A better idea is to use a language that has a library for computing base64 values, so that everything is handled in one process. An example using Perl

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print encode_base64($_)' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: i am using echo -n -i (i for ignoring/hide not printable characters, n for the newline ) ... i was not able to fit that in the $_ , so your encoding does not consider this.  But it is pretty quick, about 200MB / 5seconds.

Comment: The perl line is the same as running `base64 < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt` -- but doesn't produce the same output as reading the input line by line (the difference being newlines are maintained in the slow version).

Comment: @gilez No, it isn't; each line of the input file is encoded and printed separately.

Comment: @snapo: I don't know what you expect `echo -i` to do -- every version of echo I'm familiar with will just echo the string `-i` -- but you can chop the trailing newline in Perl by changing the command to `'chomp;print encode_base64($_)'`. (If it is a text file, why would it have non-printing characters? For that matter, why do you find it necessary to base64 encode a text file?)

Comment: @chepner, thanks you very much it was because the chomp was missing to remove those non printable controls.

Comment: @chepner, I stand corrected. Admittedly I didn't check the perl version, just the bash side.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use perl, or any of the other dyn typed languages, to process 10G of text, especially if: constrained to serial processing, expect the source payload to increase over time and/or have some SLA around processing time.

If order doesn't matter, then definitely bypass the high-level language approach, because you can process in parallel for free, just using shell and posix components.

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" one two three
one
two
three
$ printf "%s\n" one two three \
> | xargs \
>      -P3 `# three parallel processes` \
>      -L1 `# use one line from stdin` \
>     -- sh -c 'echo $@ | base64' _ 
b25lCg==
dHdvCg==
dGhyZWUK
```

Even if order (as read, as processed, as written) is a constraint, I would still take advantage of the available multiple cores and fan-out the work to multiple handlers and then fan-in to some reducer-like, single process.

```sh
# add line number to each line
$ printf "%s\n" one two three | nl
     1  one
     2  two
     3  three
# base64 encode second column
$ printf "%s\n" one two three \
>     | nl \
>     | xargs -P3 -L1 sh -c \
>       'echo $2 | base64 | xargs printf "%s %s\n" "$1"' _
2 dHdvCg==
1 b25lCg==
3 dGhyZWUK
# sort based on numeric value of first col
$ printf "%s\n" one two three \
>     | nl \
>     | xargs -P3 -L1 sh -c \
>       'echo $2 | base64 | xargs printf "%s %s\n" "$1"' _ \
>     | sort -k1 -n
1 b25lCg==
2 dHdvCg==
3 dGhyZWUK
```

All of these approaches will scale to the number of available cores and all of the heavy lifting, in terms of text processing, are being done by ancient, c binaries, which will outperform anything else.

If you are a satist, do the whole thing in C, but i can promise that the above will outperform anything written in perl, python, ruby, et al. The kernel will manage buffers between pipes, which means most of the esoteric, awful work, is done.

Comment: pufff.. `Don't use perl, or any of the other dyn typed languages, to process 10G` why not? `All of these approaches will scale` and just happen to work because line buffering is properly managed on linux, but there's no guarantee that lines from parallel processes will not interchange each other. All your snippets will improperly handle lines with `-e` or with spaces. Use quotes around expansions and use `printf "%s\n" "$1"` instead of `echo`.

Comment: 1: "why not" : GIL

Comment: 1: "why not" : GIL
2: "just happen to work because line buffering is properly managed on linux,": lol, not a small deal
3: "parallel processes will not interchange": you mean interleave and its an example fun guy
4: "Use quotes.. "$1" instead of echo." no idea what you are talking about - one is one, not a parameter  
5: "pufff": its "pffft" - "puff" is slang for homosexual 
:: Take a breath dude - i know the perl comment hurt, but its not that serious.

Comment: `no idea what you are talking about` about word splitting. Compare `printf "%s\n" -E -e -n "a        b" | xargs -d'\n' -n1 -- sh -c -x 'echo $@ | base64' _ ` with `printf "%s\n" -E -e -n "a        b" | xargs -d'\n' -n1 -- sh -c -x 'printf "%s\n" "$@" | base64' _`. See [why is printf better then echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: The point of the example was to illustrate how parallelism would benefit the OP, versus the algorithm cost o(n) of a single-process, serial-iterative approach. No one is here to provide proofed work, and no one should expect it.